# Question about the phrase「挑みかかる手前な顔」

Tags: grammar

I cannot understand the meaning of 手前 in the following sentence. As far as I know 手前 means "in front of my/your hands" or could be a pronoun. However I haven't seen before the usage like in the sentence below, so could you please explain the meaning.

> 着物姿の女の子なんて珍しいから、つい眼で追いかけてしまっていた。眼が合って、彼女は口を引き結んで、僕の前で挑みかかる**手前な**顔をして。

Translation attempt:

> "Because it is pretty rare to see a girl wearing kimono, my eyes
>   unintentionally followed her. Our eyes met, she tighten one's jaw and
>   right in front of me..."

~Edited:
I think I'm more or less understand the meaning, thanks to Brandon. But I also can't figure out why it's used な here, as if 手前 is na-adjective?

Comment: Cannot say if I have ever seen a "Verb + 手前 + な + Noun" structure before.  This sounds very "new" to me.  It also sounds highly colloquial if not slangy.  In "better" writings, one would use 「のような」 or at least 「の」 instead of 「な」.

Comment: I understand the need for this kind of expansionary use of na-adjetive to express something like difference between 女の子の仕草 (behavior of the girl) and 女の子なしぐさ (girly behavior). The most prominent use I've heard in these years is 世界で一番 お ひ め さ ま！ (to be most princess-ish in the world).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

手前【てまえ】 has a number of uses; the pronoun being the much rarer case. Here it means "before" as in time.

挑みかかる手前な顔
A face one would make just before initiating a challenge.

> My eyes locked onto her; what with a girl dressed in a kimono being far from common.
>   Our eyes met and she pursed her lips and made a face as if to say "bring it on".